# Does someone know this tire's origin? What set contains this piece?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, piece-information, set-numbering

I bought a box of LEGO in a second-hand store for my niece and in it was 4 of these wheels. Can someone help me find it so I can build the rest?[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's [*Part #32197 - Wheel 81.6 x 34 ZR Three Spoke Swirl*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32197&idColor=67#T=C&C=67). made only for one set.

[image]

*[Set #8448 - Super Street Sensation](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=8448-1)*.

[image]

Comment: That is an awesome set to have - desired by many as it is considered to be one of the best Technic cars ever made.